# Image viewer for Windows able to upload to imgur

Tags: windows, images, image-editor, image-viewer

I'm looking for a free graphics viewer for Windows 7. I am currently using Xnview. I'd like new graphics viewer to be able to:

1. resize, crop and do other simple image editing
2. upload images to imgur or other image hoster.

It would be great if the program has brush and eraser tools.